# how to php get meta tag from external url Without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I have many inputs on my page like

```
user name
URL
Des
keywords
bl bl
```

I need to get the meta tags from an URL the user enters in the `URL` input with JavaScript or Ajax 
because I need not to reload the page.

I know I can use `get_meta_tags('single_URL');`, but i need to get the metas from the URL on submit :

Here's my code :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com/");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```

I would call it as such :

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com/"); //<< I need to set the url with the user input without reloading the page
```

Comment: it seems you know how to get the php working , where's the ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `xhr`, `XMLHttpRequest` or more commonly : **AJAX**.

Assuming you are using JQuery :

**Client side :**

```
<script>
function get_metas(){
    url = $('#txt_url').val();
    $('#result').load('your_script.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
}
</script>

<form id='search' method='post' onsubmit='get_metas();return false;'>
<input type='text' id='txt_url' name='url'/>
<input type='submit' value='OK'>
</form>

<div id='result'></div>
```

**Server side :**

```
...
$html = file_get_contents_curl($_GET['url']);
...
```

Be careful though as this can potentially turn your server into a proxy to do bad things.

Comment: Loïc I did not have any results through your own code 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: url

Filename: controllers/addsite.php

Line Number: 22
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/addsite.php